# VBA: Got to check record set EOF using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I apologize in advance if the title of my question is not accurate enough.

I would like to know how to convert a statement such as:

```
ADORS.Open "SELECT * FROM commerce_product WHERE pf_id = '" & PID & "'", , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If ADORS.EOF Then
    ' Do this
Else
    ' Do that
End If
```

Rather than have the SQL query in the VBA code, I would like to call a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: Do you simply want to know the row(s) exists?  Or do you want to look at the column values for the (possibly) returned row(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the procedure:

```sql
create procedure dbo.DoSomething @id int
begin
    select * from dbo.commerce_product where pf_id = @id
end
```

Then modify your VBA code to run a parameterized `Command`; instead of "opening a recordset", you `Execute` the command and *get* a recordset:

```vb
Dim adoConnection As New ADODB.Connection
adoConnection.ConnectionString = "connection string"
adoConnection.Open

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "DoSomething" ' the name of the stored procedure

Dim param As New ADODB.Parameter
param.Type = adInteger
param.Direction = adParamInput
param.Value = 42 'the ID value
cmd.Parameters.Append param

Dim result As ADODB.Recordset
Set result = cmd.Execute
```

From there it's the same *iterating a recordset* story (notice the `BOF` check - `BOF` will be `True` if there are no records):

```vb
While Not result.BOF And Not result.EOF
    'will loop as long as there are records
    result.MoveNext
Wend
```

And don't forget to close both your recordset and the connection when you're done:

```vb
result.Close
adoconnection.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @PID varchar(24)
select @PID = 'abc'

if exists ( SELECT * FROM commerce_product WHERE pf_id = @PID )
BEGIN
    Select 'it exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select 'it does not exist'
END
```

=========APPEND

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RecordsExist
( @PID varchar(24)
 ,@MyOutValue bit OUTPUT)
AS

if exists ( SELECT * FROM commerce_product WHERE pf_id = @PID )
BEGIN
    Select @MyOutValue = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select @MyOutValue = 1
END

RETURN

GO
```

...

Test it in TSQL Land

```
DECLARE @PID varchar(24)
       ,@MyOutValue         int
SET @PID='abc'
EXEC dbo.RecordsExist @PID, @MyOutValue OUTPUT
PRINT @MyOutValue
```

---

Then follow this article to wire up your ADODB call... to get an output parameter

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194792

But something like this:

```
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"

cnn.Open cnn.ConnectionString

Set cmd = New adodb.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.RecordsExist"


Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter
               ("@PID", adChar, adParamInput, 1, "abc")
cmd.Parameters.Append param1

Set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter
               ("@MyOutValue", adBit, adParamOutput, , adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append param2

rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open cmd


Set myResult = cmd.Parameters("MyOutValue")
```